# Recursive Javascript function using callback not working

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to fix a problem with my recursive function JS using a call back. I just want to update the HTML of 3 div using according to an index. Please find the code below

```
<div id="try0">50</div>
<div id="try1">50</div>
<div id="try2">50</div>

function getNumberOfAnswers(questionID, callback)
{
  var value = i*10;
   callback( value.toString());

}

var i=0;
getNumberOfAnswers(i, function callFunc(ratio){
    var itemToChg = 'try'+i;
document.getElementById(itemToChg).innerHTML = ratio;
    if(i<3){
        i++;
        getNumberOfAnswers(i,callFunc(ratio));

    }

    });
```

I didn't put any tags on the code above to simplify but I made a JSfiddle with it. http://jsfiddle.net/cyrilGa/zmtQ8/ . On the third line from the end, I tried to write getNumberOfAnswers(i,ratio);  but it didn't work.
Can somebody help me with this
Cheers

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to fix this imbricated call/declaration structure but I think you just choose the most complex way to do a simple thing. Can you explain what you exactly try to do ?

Comment: Saying "it didn't work" is useless. What did you expect? What actually happened? What errors did you get?

Comment: My actual problem is actually is bit more complex than the one above so I tried to simplify it. I am querying a parse.com database using Javascript asynchronously 10 times.  So I have to wait for the end of one query (hence the callback) before querying it again. (hence the recursive part). With each result from the database, I am updating the value inside a div. Hope this is clear

Comment: You are right, I should have explained a bit more, I expected to have 0 in the div Try0, 10 in the Try1, and 20 in the Try3. I get 0 on all divs. So it is not incrementing the index

Comment: The callback calls back with the given ratio instead of referencing the function: getNumberOfAnswers(i,callFunc);

Comment: You'd have been better off describing the actual problem than this oversimplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
var value = i*10;
```

should be

```
var value = questionID * 10;
```

And I think

```
getNumberOfAnswers(i,callFunc(i));
```

Should be:

```
getNumberOfAnswers(i,callFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use recursion for this, it is silly.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    document.getElementById('try' + i).innerHTML = i * 10;
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: My actual problem is actually is bit more complex than the one above so I tried to simplify it. I am querying a parse.com database using Javascript asynchronously 10 times. So I have to wait for the end of one query (hence the callback) before querying it again. (hence the recursive part). With each result from the database, I am updating the value inside a div. Hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the recursive `callFunc(ratio);` at the bottom to `callFunc(i);` because the argument `ratio` is still equal to 0 while you increment `i`. Everything else is fine.

Comment: When I use callFunc(i), the function actually returns i. What I expect is to get i*10;